# assert_not_in_array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing

We have an assertion in rails tests assert_in_array that is used to check if an element exists in an array. Is there any reverse assertion for it like assert_not_in_array?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is no such assertion, however you could do this:

```
assert (not array.include? element)
```

Answer (score 5):

You might be looking for `refute_includes`

```
 refute_includes array_of_user_ids, user.id
```

http://apidock.com/ruby/v1_9_3_392/MiniTest/Assertions/refute_includes

Answer (score 3):

another method is using `assert_not_includes`

so expanding on the answer from @drhenner, one could use:

```rb
assert_not_includes array_of_user_ids, user.id
```